# Como obtener el id de un directorio del google drive cuando el nombre se repite

Tags: google-api, google-drive

Tengo la siguiente situación, tengo en mi unidad de **google drive** varios directorios que se llaman igual. Estos se encuentran dentro de otro directorio con otro nombre que este si seria distinto.

**Ejemplo:**

1. **EME/2019-04-ABR**
2. **JBL/2019-04-ABR**

Los directorios raíces son, **EME** y **JBL** y dentro de ella tengo el directorio que se me repite **2019-04-ABR**. El problema que se me esta presentado es que cuando quiero que me de el **id** del directorio **2019-04-ABR** que esta dentro **EME** me entrega el de **JBL**. Me pregunta es la siguiente de que forma puedo obtener el id del directorio que se encuentra dentro de **EME** cuando lo requiera y viceversa. Aquí les dejo el código para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Gracias.

```
   $pageToken = null;
    do {

        $response = $driveService->files->listFiles(array(
            'q' => mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name contains '2019-04-ABR',
            'spaces' => 'drive',
            'pageToken' => $pageToken,
            'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
        ));

        foreach ($response->files as $file) {
            $idFolder = $file->id;
        }

        $pageToken = $repsonse->pageToken;
    } while ($pageToken != null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación oficial](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files#examples_for_fileslist), te falta especificar dentro de qué folder es que querés hacer la búsqueda. Cuando se omite esta especificación, el resultado retornado es el primero que encuentra.

Para solucionar tu problema, primero en la interfaz de Google Drive, abrí el folder **EME** y copiá el **id**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después, simplemente modificá tu código para que se vea de esta manera:

```
$response = $driveService->files->listFiles(array(
    'q' => "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and name contains '2019-04-ABR' and '1kbannXxcU8ICI7Y6QivnfBXao2Yklm22' in parents",
    'spaces' => 'drive',
    'pageToken' => $pageToken,
    'fields' => 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)',
)); // request service
```

De esta manera estarás especificando dentro de qué folder en específico querés realizar la búsqueda.